# How to fix "Error in opening default parameter file" error in terminal

Tags: c++, terminal

I am attempting to run a c++ file through terminal, but when trying to execute, I get an error saying "Error in opening default parameter file" which is rather ambiguous. Anyone know what this error might be referring to? This is most likely not enough information, so if I should include anything else, let me know.

Comment: What compiler/OS? Give details about the environment.

Comment: C++ version, and can you paste the code here??

Comment: What do you mean by *run a c++ file*? The naive interpretation suggests you expect C++ source code to be executable like a script. It's not. You must compile the source code into an executable and then run the executable.

Comment: It is compiled into an executable, but trying to run the executable gives the error mentioned before.

Comment: /usr/local/bin/t7 ; exit;
x ~ % /usr/local/bin/t7 ; exit;
Error in opening default parameter file
 ... exiting ...

[Process completed]